# Wrong table formatting bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, echo

Hi I have a problem with this code in php, in practice in this table I want to cycle various information taken from the db, only if this information is of different length the formatting of each table is bad, I would like to have the same dimensions for each line, like I could do? the code works correctly, the formatting is wrong ... one column is wider than the other .I would like to leave the first line with the word "N, name, description" and cycle the rest with the same size. Sorry for english

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)) {
  echo '
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th scope="col">N°</th>
        <th scope="col">name</th>
        <th scope="col">description</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">' . $_id . '</th>
        <td>' . $_name . '</td>
        <td>' . $_description . '</td>
   <td>' . $_lingua . '</td>
   <td> <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
   value="Send"></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>';
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `<table>` parts and the table header to outside of the PHP loop, so the loop is only iterating through each data item and adding a new table row instead of generating a whole new table for every piece of info.

```
echo '<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">N°</th>
            <th scope="col">name</th>
            <th scope="col">description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)) {
  echo '<tr>
          <th scope="row">' . $_id . '</th>
          <td>' . $_name . '</td>
          <td>' . $_description . '</td>
          <td>' . $_lingua . '</td>
          <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send"></td>
        </tr>';
}

echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
```

Comment: I would like to ask you one last thing, on smartphone this table is not responsive, how can I do? the length of the line goes further and I have to shake to the right to see it all

Comment: I'm not sure, @GiacomoCorcella. You could set `max-width: 100%;` in CSS on `<table>` and then do some extra text wrapping with `word-break: break-all;`, but that probably won't look very nice. It really depends on how much content is in each cell. I might be tempted to pick a different layout for mobile. In the past, I've used an accordion with each 'row' of data being shown as its own accordion section. Each section had 2 columns, the first being the data label, the second being the data.

Comment: in fact the effect is not beautiful, would you know for example tell me how at the end of the edge of the smartphone the columns go down so as to have everything on two lines for example? I know I have to use media queries but I can't apply it correctly. Thanks for the help you're giving me :)

Comment: Do you mean to have each cell breaking onto a new line, so one table row becomes multiple table rows?

Comment: @wlabaroon no, because if I did it this way it would be very long, I mean that every 3 columns would come to create a line, or at least when you reach the end of the border on the smartphone you would go to a new line

Comment: Does putting the CSS `word-break: break-all;` on `<td>` do what you’re looking for, @GiacomoCorcella? If not, could you upload a drawing of what you’d like as the end result?